# Pip does not want to be installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Pip does not find in the console. When I try to download it through get-pip, it produces the following errors in the console. I downloaded the latest version 3.7.4 from the official site. The same was observed with other versions. How to fix it?

```
F:\pic.png>python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 21492, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 197, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip._internal
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\75E3~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmb245qvv\pip.zip\pip\_internal\__i
nit__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\75E3~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmb245qvv\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli
\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
  ******
  ******
  ******
  File "C:\Users\75E3~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmb245qvv\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\reque
sts\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\75E3~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmb245qvv\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\reque
sts\compat.py", line 64, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: With Python 3.7 you don't have to install `pip` And should not try. It is in the `Scripts` subfolder of your Python installation.

Comment: @BoarGules my folder Scripts is empty

Comment: Then your install failed. It is part of the standard install and has been since about Python 3.4.

Comment: @BoarGules And what's wrong with my system? I just noticed that I am precompiling the standard library (-O) and (-OO). Can this be a problem?

Comment: No, that is normal, as far as I know.